# slice reoccuring values using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

taking the following data

```
A <- c(4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6)
B <- c(1,2,3,1,3,4,3,2,7)

data1 <- data.frame(A,B)
```

I want to remove the duplicated B values for each A.

So my new table should remove `data1[7,]`

I want to use the `dplyr()` package
And have tried the following code

```
data2 <- data1 %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  filter(slice(B(1)))
```

Can someone help me with the correct `filter()` command

Comment: Do you really need plyr for that?
What about just calling unique(data1)?

Comment: @gvrocha In the example, maybe not, but in a real application you might want to check uniqueness with respect to only a subset of columns. I guess that's what the `group_by` is for. Similarly, in `data.table`, there is a `unique` function with a `by` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
     group_by(A) %>% 
     filter(!duplicated(B))#or
     #slice(which(!duplicated(B)))
```